# React js | Conditional rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, render

I have a problem with conditional rendering in [reactjs](/questions/tagged/reactjs).

###### Problem

If an environment is prod, then `<Sentry.ErrorBoundary>` tag should be loaded.

Is there a better way instead of using `if` with `sentrytag` and `else` without `sentrytag`?

###### Code:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        {environment == 'PROD' && <Sentry.ErrorBoundary> }
            <Experiment>
                <Root />
            </Experiment>
            {environment == 'PROD' && </Sentry.ErrorBoundary> }
    </Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a better way instead of using `if` with `sentrytag` and `else` without `sentrytag`

Yea you could define a variable with the 'wrapper' element, or an 'empty' `React.Fragment` if the element isn't needed:

```
const wrapper = (environment === 'PROD') ? Sentry.ErrorBoundary : React.Fragment;

<Provider store={store}>
    <wrapper>
        <Experiment>
            <Root />
        </Experiment>
    </wrapper>
</Provider>
```

---

Small working demo, just to give the idea.

The `Error` component is the `Sentry.ErrorBoundary` in OP's example.

Press the button to toggle the 'error' state to enable/disable the wrapper.

```js
const Error = (props) => (
    <div>
        <h1>{'Omg; error!'}</h1>
        {props.children}
    </div>
);

const Example = () => {

    const [ err, setErr ] = React.useState(true);
    const Wrapper = (err) ? Error : React.Fragment;
    
    return (
        <div>
            <Wrapper>
                Hello!
            </Wrapper>
            <br /><br /><br />
            <button onClick={() => setErr(!err)}>Toggle</button>
        </div>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```